# How to allow users to create an arbitrary number of strings

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm new to ASP.NET. I'm creating a simple website that allows users to create charts. On the front-end I'm using Charts.js, where the data for each chart looks like this:

```
var data = {
    labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
    datasets: [
        {
            label: "My First dataset",
            fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
            strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            pointColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
            pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
            pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40]
        }
    ]
};
```

My plan is to create a data model for charts that will allow a user to specify the various properties of a chart. Below is my model:

Below is my class. Assume each chart will only have one dataset for now:

```
public class Chart
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string fillColor { get; set; }
    public string strokeColor { get; set; }
    public string pointColor { get; set; }
}
```

My question is, what is the best way to handle the labels property? Should I just include it as another string property on the class, let the user enter each label into an input box separated by semicolons, and then iterate through it to populate the labels property on the JavaScript object? Or is there a better way?

Note: I'm not worried about the `data` integer array on the chart. All starting values for that will be 0 so I will hard-code it.

Comment: It should be a `list of string` property. `public List<string> labels { get; set; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would prefer to keep the model like below.

```
   public class Dataset
    {
        public string label { get; set; }
        public string fillColor { get; set; }
        public string strokeColor { get; set; }
        public string pointColor { get; set; }
        public string pointStrokeColor { get; set; }
        public string pointHighlightFill { get; set; }
        public string pointHighlightStroke { get; set; }
        public List<int> data { get; set; }
    }

    public class Chart
    {
        public List<string> labels { get; set; }
        public List<Dataset> datasets { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. Does it matter if these two classes are in the same Model (.cs) file, or separate?

Comment: yes of course, i just gave the core model , you may add as per ur req.

Comment: Thanks. Last question: do they use the same DBContext? Or different? I assume since Datasets are created/edited only inside Charts, they share the same DBContext.

Comment: they should share the same DBcontext .